# Need help formulating regular expression to parse data

Tags: c#, regex

Basically,

I have text I want to spit out from a block of text. I have the regular expression down for the most part however, It's either too little[skips a section] or too much[reads part of the next section].It basically needs to read text that I extracted from a bank statement.I already tried reading up on regular expressions more, however I still have no clue as to what to do.

Heres a bit of a sample for you guys to understand what I'm trying to do.

```
_4XXXXXXXXXXXXXX9_
_SOU THE HOME DEPOT 431      POMPANO BEACH * FL
AUT  020112 DDA PURCHASE_
_2/1_DEBIT POS_3.15_
```

The underscores are basically parts I want to extract. Basically everything except the DEBIT POS basically.

And the regex I'm using is:

```
\A
(?<SerialNumber>\b[0-9]{13,16}\b)
(?<Description>.) 'PROBLEM HERE'
(?<PostingDate>
(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))
(?<Amount>[,0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})
\Z
```

I cant set the Description to be from any length of characters because I don't know the maximum length that the text portion will be. I also don't know if it's 2 lines for description or just 1. Thats mainly whats confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you want to join every four lines together as one line first:

```
var file = @"C:\temp.txt";
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
var buffer = new List<String>();

for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++ )
{
    if (i % 4 == 0) { buffer.Add(""); }
    buffer[buffer.Count - 1] += lines[i] + " ";
}

buffer.ForEach(b => Console.WriteLine(b));
```

Then you can actually parse each entry in buffer as if it's one line. This can be done easily using either regex or just string Substrings. Far easier than trying to do it across lines.

The above code isn't the cleanest, but it works.

Comment: I can't join all the lines together first. And I also need to determine weather the description will also be one line or two. Main reason why I'm using regex's in the first place.

Also read the comment to @Erik

Comment: It doesn't have to be 4 lines every time. You can change the 4 in the code above to a variable and decide dynamically on each start line how many more to grab before parsing. The suggestion is primarily that doing it in two passes is easier. One to join related lines together, and the second to extract data from those lines. What are the identifying aspects of each type of record?

Answer (score 0):

Look like another simple answer of don't use Regex.  If each of these are lines, it wouldn't be that hard to [`File.ReadAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) and parse each line.

```
public class Order
{
  public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public DateTime PostingDate { get; set; }
  public Decimal Amount { get; set; }

  public void SetSerialNumberFromRaw(string serialNumber)
  {
    // Convert to required type, etc.
    this.SerialNumber = <someConvertedValue>;
  }
  public void <OtherNeededValueConverters>
}    

List<string> lines = File.ReadAlllines("<filename").ToList();
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

Order currentOrder = null;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
  if (currentOrder = null)
  {
    currentOrder = new Order();
    orders.Add(currentOrder);
    currentOrder.SetSerialNumberFromRaw(line);
  }
  else
  {
    if (line.Contains("DEBIT POS", CultureInfo.CurrentCultureIngoreCase))
    { 
      currentOrder.SetPostingDateAndAmount(line);
      currentOrder = null;
    }
    else
    {
      currentOrder.SetAppendDescription(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm using regex's is because I need to know if the first line is going to be a Debit transaction or if it's a check and what not. They vary by line length[extracted from PDF and had to remove all garbage.]

I cannot say all the transactions will have DEBIT POS.
+ 4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX3
+ SHELL OIL 57529380602       COCONUT CREEK * FL
+ AUT  021012 VISA DDA PUR
+ 2/10DEBIT CARD PURCHASE35.05

or even swap right after a debit transaction and contain daily balances.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be to hard to setup two objects (or as many as you need), running regex on the first line to detected the type, and then run code that fits that object until you've read to the end of the object.